# How to add ANN in python smote_variants model_selection?

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, smote

I am working with the library smote-variants for python (https://pypi.org/project/smote-variants/) and I want to use the method model_selection to select the best classifier and the best resampling method. I do it just like this:

```
lista_oversamplers = sv.get_all_oversamplers()

samp_obj, cl_obj = sv.model_selection(dataset = dataset,
                                    samplers = lista_oversamplers,
                                    classifiers = list_classifiers,
                                    cache_path = cache_path,
                                    n_jobs = 5,
                                    max_samp_par_comb = 10)
```

CLassifiers such as KNN or RandomForestClassifier can be included as a list of classifiers in sv.model_selection(), but what if I would like to include an ANN implementation? How can I do it? Is there a way?

Comment: I'm a developer of smote-variants. Please open a ticket on the GitHub page of the package and provide a brief discussion on what type of ANN do you want to use with smote-variants. It certainly can be done.